# Wordpress Facebook Instant Articles not seeing our articles / content

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

Before the community dismisses this - this is not a repeat of other issues with the Facebook submission process. Were a non-profit looking for help getting this running.

We have many articles on our website but we are not able to get them to appear in https://childmind.org/feed/instant-articles

I am not able to see where you instruct the FB Instant Articles WordPress plugin which content you want to publish e.g. our articles aren't in /blog but rather in /article e.g. https://childmind.org/article/adhd-behavior-problems/

Everything else is configured seemingly properly. Does anyone have an idea?

After we get articles in the feed, we can submit for review.

NOTE: We *have* edited and saved articles to "trigger" them being added but has not worked.

Comment: This website is _about programming_.  Saying _Were a non-profit looking for help getting this running._  doesn't make this a unique question or a "better fit" for SO.  Your question unfortunately smacks of all the typical issues: links to your site (that's a no-no), no code (that's a no-no), asking for advice about a plugin (why not ask the plugin author?), not including relevant details (what's the "key" for your custom post type?), not showing any research effort.... did you see this article? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-this-plugin-work-with-my-custom-post-type/

Answer (score 0):

Articles sound like a custom post type which you need to manually tell the plugin by using a filter for your CPT.

```
add_filter( 'instant_articles_post_types', 'add_post_types', 10,1 );
function add_post_types($post_type_array){
    array_push($post_type_array,'post'); // Standard post "blog"
    array_push($post_type_array,'articles'); // The name of your custom post.
    return $post_type_array;
}
```

This should then get pull the articles for the feed as long as everything else has been set up correctly. Taken from a post on the [WP Plugin forum.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-this-plugin-work-with-my-custom-post-type/)

Note: Also, Facebook have their own validation process once you get this working before you will start to see them on Facebook.

Comment: How about changing the key of the custom post type? And by the way, it's usually good form to _reference the source_ when you post code from somewhere else...  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-this-plugin-work-with-my-custom-post-type/

Comment: I've added the source of the code. Changed the key but it might not help if they have registered the CPT as something else.

Comment: Thank you @Kyon147 ... you've been genuinely helpful. We'll have our developers put this into action and see if we get a result.